# How to get the index of visible child in GTK.Stack

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject

Is possible get the index of visible in Gtk.Stack?

Example:

```
>>> stack = Gtk.Stack()
>>> stack.add_named(any_widget1, 'any_widget1') # Index 0
>>> stack.add_named(any_widget2, 'any_widget2') # Index 1
>>> stack.add_named(any_widget3, 'any_widget3') # Index 2
>>>
>>> stack.get_visible_child_index()
0
```

This is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Stack documentation includes `position` child property:

```
child = stack.get_visible_child()
if child is not None:
    position = stack.child_get_property(child, "position")
```

Comment: I always forget to look at the child properties.